Calculating how much days it takes for the chance that event occurs is larger than a lower bound
Context: electrical vehicles in an underground car park and the likelihood it will spontaneously combust. I want to calculate this for the safety considerations as current underground car park just bans all EVs due to this risk.
I estimate that the chance that an EV combusts on a singly day is about 1 in 10 million. Just as an approximation, I'd refine this number later.
I then estimate that there would be about, on average, 5 EVs a day in the park. so that gives a 1 in 2 million chance for one of them combusting. This is P
To then calculate the chance, I'd take the chance the event doesn't occur (1-P) and then equate this to 1 percent as a lower bound (so 0.01) for x amounts of years (so x*365)
My equation would then be:
(1-1/2,000,000)^(x*365)=0.01

Solving this for x, using Wolfram alpha, gives x = 25233.8 years.
This doesn't seem correct. A sanity check by ChatGPT (who uses Poisson) gives 55 years which seems more correct. However, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong (and ChatGPT starts hallucinating).
Can you help?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

"A sanity check by ChatGPT" , no please not.

From google:"online calculator" :: $\displaystyle \ln\left[ ~1 - \frac{1}{2000000} ~\right] \approx -0.000002.~$  Therefore, $~\color{red}{\text{what}}~$?

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

For what it's worth, ChatGPT has a notoriously bad reputation.  The general rule is to use ChatGPT for entertainment value only, but never to rely on its analysis.

What is the meaning of the $0.01$? Without that "bound" I get round about 5479.453 expected years for the first accident.
